# Using App Engine with a .info domain

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm having problems assigning a .info domain to my GAE project. The problem is I cannot get a GAE account, enven by inviting the admin of my .info domain to be a developer on the project.

Anybody knows if GAE supports .info domains?

Thnxs!

A.

Answer (score 0):

You can map any domain to an App Engine app. Simply purchase the app with a registrar, set it up with Google Apps (which you appear to have already done), and add the App Engine app as a service on the domain, as described [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html). It's not necessary for the owner of the domain to be an admin on the app, or vice-versa.